# Multiple MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, vb.net

If I only add one query such as `hostnameQuery` the code works fine, as you can see I have tried to add multiple.

I've tried using `+ and &` on the MySqlCommand but I get a syntax error returned.

```
Dim hostnameQuery As String = "SELECT `HOSTNAME` FROM `m1` WHERE 1"
    Dim osQuery As String = "SELECT `OS` FROM `m1` WHERE 1"
    Dim SQLConnection As New MySqlConnection(My.Settings.connStr)
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand(hostnameQuery & osQuery, SQLConnection)

    Try
        SQLConnection.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            main.Label64.Text = (reader.GetString(0))
            main.Label65.Text = (reader.GetString(0))
        End While
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    Finally
        SQLConnection.Close()

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
Dim hostnameQuery As String = "SELECT `HOSTNAME` FROM `m1` WHERE 1 UNION ALL (SELECT `OS` FROM `m1` WHERE 1)";
```

or you why not (since you quering 1 table):

```
 Dim hostnameQuery As String = "SELECT `HOSTNAME`,`OS`  FROM `m1` WHERE 1 ";

 .....

While reader.Read
            main.Label64.Text = (reader.GetString(0))
            main.Label65.Text = (reader.GetString(1))
```

Comment: But I need it to update two different text boxes for hostname and OS.